# How to display content of DIV Tag of a HTML page on second monitor screen?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to display content of DIV tags on multi monitor screens scenario. On my HTML page, we are having four DIV with contents. All for tags having drag-drop functionality implemented. As per requirement, user can pick any tag out of four and can drag on one of three monitors screen and the content of that DIV will display in full screen mode on dropped monitor screen.

Can anyone please suggest any implementation for such requirement.

Comment: what do you really mean @SarbjitHanjra

Comment: do you require multiple tab or just single instance tab.

Comment: I am having a html page with four DIV tages (layout is 2 columns and two rows), all four div can swap able using drag-drop functionality. Now as per desired requirement, user want to pick any one DIV and can drop on second monitor screen and second screen should display that DIV content .

Answer (score 3):

JS in a browser doesn't have that level of access to the OS. You can't do that.

Comment: Its true that JS can have access only within browser but there must be workaround or third party tool available to complete the requirement. I am looking for anyway to implement requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand your question, but this might help you.

For dragging implemention:

Try use interact.js http://interactjs.io/
(JavaScript drag and drop, resizing and multi-touch gestures with inertia and snapping for modern browsers )

Here is an example similar to what you need. 
see here http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/01/11/dragging-and-dropping-images-from-one-browser-tab-to-another-in-angularjs/

You will have to open two browser tabs of the same site/webapp. For example; on the left is your source and on the right (monitor) is your dropping point.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for comment but drag and drop functionality is already implemented. I just want to drop one DIV (contents) to second Monitor screen. I am working in multi-monitor environment. Hopefully you understand the scenario now.

Comment: I think you can achieve it using Angular.JS but you will need to open two browser tabs, one on left as source and on on right as droping point. You will need to get the session from same browser windows. @SarbjitHanjra

Answer (score 0):

Even if I do agree with @Quentin's answer that it is impossible,

Here is the closest I can think of :
- but I'm not sure it will open in the dropped screen, this is most likely really dependent of the os,
- and users will need to click into the popup to get the page goes fullscreen.

```js
var drag = document.getElementById('drag');
drag.draggable = true;
drag.addEventListener('dragover', function(e){e.preventDefault();}, false);
drag.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e){e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', '');}, false);
drag.addEventListener('dragend', openClone, false);

function openClone(e){
    // create a clone of our div
    var elem = drag.cloneNode(true);
    // create a new script element that will contain the fullscreen code
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = 'document.onclick='+polyFullScreen.toString();
    elem.appendChild(script);
    // create a new blob from our div
    var blob = new Blob([elem.outerHTML], {
         type: "text/html"
        });   
    // make it into an objectUrl
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // open the popup
    var popup = window.open(url, "popup" ,'width="100%", height="100%"');
    }

var polyFullScreen = function(e){
    var elem = e.target;
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x0tmmdkw/2/)